# Usage of Wget for a long URL

Tags: linux, shell, unix, wget

I am trying to download a file with the below URL:

> wget http://example.com/reports/downloadreport?roleId=8&loginName=9011613&code=123

But it takes only till

> http://example.com/reports/downloadreport?roleId=8

not sending the remaining things. I need to send at least role ID and `loginName` to get the file.

I tried to create a shell script like below, but that is not working either:

`i="http://euroams.eurekaforbes.co.in:8080/efms/reports/bamsinvoiceresultdownload?roleId=8&loginName=9011613"
wget --tries=45 -i $i`

How can I fix this?

Comment: use TinyUrl, Visit this http://tinyurl.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose the URL in quotes. Your shell is interpreting the "&" rather than passing it as a parameter, so it's seeing what you typed as the following (three commands rather than one):

```
wget http://example.com/reports/downloadreport?roleId=8 &
loginName=9011613 & 
code=123
```

Comment: Dear Mark, I got below error __**HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.
Retrying. **__